SwiftData no such table error for one of models
I have 2 models in my app, fist (ModelA) is working fine - data is persistent no matter how many times I restart app on the simulator, but the second (ModelB) sometimes losts it data and I see errors about no such table found in Xcode debugger. I don't understand what is the difference between them.
@Model
final class ModelA: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var name: String
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
final class ModelB: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var param: String
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, param: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.param = param
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            ModelA.self,
            ModelB.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView { /* === views === */ }
       }.modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
}


upd
I wasn't able to find the root cause and fix it (even though it is data fetch issue I believe it relates to how view hierarchy is structured), but I found workaround instead - I made second model a struct (Identifiable, Codable, Hashable)

Unrelated but you don’t need to conform to Identifiable since this is already included when conforming to PersistentModel which you do with the @Model macro. So the id property is also not needed since one already exists.

As for the issue itself there is very little info provided so it’s hard knowing what is going on. Could there be a problem using TabView directly in the Scene body? Whether it is or not I believe we need more information.
